# How can I concatenate multiple fields into 1 result?

Tags: c#, linq

We've got a table in SQL Server that has values that are to appear in a couple of textboxes, if those textboxes are initially empty. Then the user can either add more details to the pre-loaded text, or remove it, whatever. It's to get the user started. Here's the table's schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PreloadTextbox](
[PreLoadNumber] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[DisplayOrder] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[LineToDisplay] [varchar](100) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_PreloadTextbox] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[PreLoadNumber] ASC,
[DisplayOrder] ASC
  )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

This table was initially used for a VB6 app written many years ago. We're re-writing it in WPF using C#. The field PreLoadNumber is associated with the textbox it's associated with, and of course the DisplayOrder is what order the records should appear in. What we should do is combine all of the records in the table into 1 large record, change the LineToDisplay from a VARCHAR(100) to VARCHAR(MAX), but that will have to wait until another day, as this table is still being used by the old VB6 app.

So what I'm hoping to find out is this; is it possible to combine all LineToDisplay for say PreLoadNumber == 1 (in the order specified by DisplayOrder) using LINQ? And if so, how is that done?

Comment: What separator is used for the join? Where do you want to put the join result in? a variable? or back to somewhere in your table?

Comment: The separator would be a character return/newline feed, so that it will look right in a WPF text box.

I want the result to be available as a variable.

Comment: if so the answer of `Kaf` should be what you want (replace ',' with '\r\n'). Have you even tried it yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to solve it might be to add a SQL Server View like this:

```
SELECT  pt.PreLoadNumber AS [PreLoadNumber]
       ,( SELECT    SUB.LineToDisplay AS [text()]
          FROM      [PreLoadTextbox] SUB
          WHERE     SUB.PreLoadNumber = pt.PreLoadNumber
          ORDER BY  SUB.DisplayOrder
        FOR
          XML PATH('')
        ) AS [LinesToDisplay]
FROM    ( SELECT DISTINCT
                    PreLoadNumber
          FROM      [PreLoadTextbox]
        ) pt
```

This probably will increase performance because pre-compilation of the view. That view will get you a two-column view with `PreLoadNumber`, and all its `LineToDisplay` concatenated in the `DisplayOrder` without a delimiter between them. If you need a delimiter you can use:

```
SELECT  pt.PreLoadNumber AS [PreLoadNumber]
       ,STUFF((   SELECT    ',' + SUB.LineToDisplay AS [text()]
          FROM      [PreLoadTextbox] SUB
          WHERE     SUB.PreLoadNumber = pt.PreLoadNumber
          ORDER BY  SUB.DisplayOrder
        FOR
          XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 1, '' ) AS [LinesToDisplay]
FROM    ( SELECT DISTINCT
                    PreLoadNumber
          FROM      [PreLoadTextbox]
        ) pt
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are searching for something like this:

```
var results = dbContext.PreloadTextbox
                       .Where(x=> x.PreLoadNumber == 1)
                       .OrderBy(x=> x.DisplayOrder)
                       .Select(x=> x.LineToDisplay)
                       .ToArray();

//string array is joined here using a ",", change it as necessary 
string output = string.Join(",", results);
```

Comment: The `Select` shouldn't be there.  There's no value added in putting the column into an anonymous object with no other data, and in fact it makes the results of the `Join` incorrect.

Comment: Thanks @Servy, I have removed the anonymous object.

Comment: put this on the end of select instead of `.ToArray();` `.Aggregate((a, b) => a + "," + b);`